# User login form won't show up under community site

Tags: community, lightning-community

I'm trying to use `lightning` components with `a community visual force page`.

However, I found lightning components can be only showing on a VF page but not `community` VF page.

```
<aura:component description="test"
                implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"
                access="GLOBAL" >

    <c:otherLightningComponents />
</aura:component>
```

What I got from a TSO ORG is this error message `This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed: c:loginForm$controller$initialize [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {c:loginForm$controller$initialize}`. However, this message is not showing up on another dev ORG.

I try to include a lightinig login form in a visualforce page instead of `community lightning page`.
In a community lightining page builder I could see this result.

[image: inline]

Comment: what community template are you using, and how exactly are you trying to achieve this? can you include a screenshot of where it is you were expecting the component to show? any error messages whule attemptint to do so?

Comment: @glls Hi I did update on my original post, any thought will be appreciating.

Comment: does your login form have a controller? it is still unclear how you are referencing this form in your community, have you followed any documentation links to achieve this? if so, can you link it?

Comment: @glls I think the `login form` lightning component is highly coupled with the community template. It requires a bunch of environment variables I believe and there's no document to tell you how could you reuse the lightning `login form` component with a visualforce page from scratch.